# Changing generated outlook.com address

Tags: outlook.com

When I send emails from Outlook and receive replies, I notice that there's a message saying that the sender if not the address I sent from but an @outlook.com address with letters and numbers preceding it and then (on behalf of my name).

When I open Outlook mail on my computer, those same details show in the tab (see attached photo). Why does it show this there and also in my emails?

How can I change it?

[image: Outlook TAB]

Comment: You could have taken a screenshot. If you're on Windows, to take a screenshot, press the Print Screen key and paste it into an image editor like Paint by pressing CTRL+V.

Answer (score 0):

### To change your `From` address for Outlook.com:

1. Login to your account at [Outlook.com](https://outlook.com/)
2. Click on the gear icon in the upper right
3. Select **Options**
4. Select **Connected accounts** on the left sidebar (under **Mail > Accounts > Connected accounts**)
5. Under the **From address** heading, click on **Change your From address**
6. Select another email address from the drop-down list

If you don't have any other email addresses associated with your Outlook account, you'll need to add one first, in order to choose it as your `From` address.